# Extracting inner group with Scala regex

Tags: regex, scala, regex-group

My Scala app is being given a string that may or may not contain the token "`flimFlam(*)`" inside of it, where the asterisk represents any kind of text, chars, punctuation, etc. There will always only be 0 or 1 instances of "`flimFlam(*)`" in this string, never more.

I need to detect if the given input string contains a "`flimFlam(*)`" instance, and if it does, extract out whatever is inside the two parentheses. Hence, if my string contains "`flimFlam(Joe)`", then the result would be a string with a value of "`Joe`", etc.

My best attempt so far:

```
val inputStr : String = "blah blah flimFlam(Joe) blah blah"

// Regex must be case-sensitive for "flimFlam" (not "FLIMFLAM", "flimflam", etc.)
val flimFlamRegex = ".*flimFlam\\(.*?\\)".r
val insideTheParens = flimFlamRegex.findFirstIn(inputStr)
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pattern matching and regex extractor

```
val regex = ".*flimFlam\\((.*)\\).*".r

inputStr match { 
 case regex(x) => println(x)
 case _ => println("no match")
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val inputStr : String = "blah blah flimFlam(Joe) blah blah"
inputStr: String = blah blah flimFlam(Joe) blah blah

scala> val regex = ".*flimFlam\\((.*)\\).*"
regex: String = .*flimFlam\((.*)\).*

scala> val regex = ".*flimFlam\\((.*)\\).*".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*flimFlam\((.*)\).*

scala> inputStr match { case regex(x) => println(x); case _ => println("no match")}
Joe
```

Comment: unanchored as in other answer is handy to know (and promote).

Answer (score 0):

You may use a capturing group around `.*?` and just use an unanchored regex within `match` block so that the pattern could stay short and "pretty" (no need for `.*` around the value you are looking for):

```
var str = "blah blah flimFlam(Joe) blah blah"
val pattern = """flimFlam\((.*?)\)""".r.unanchored
val res = str match {
   case pattern(res) => println(res)
   case _ => "No match"
}
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/dSXAJ9)

Also, note that you do not need to double backslashes inside `"""`-quoted string literals that helps avoid excessive backslashes.

And a hint: if the `flimFlam` is a *whole word*, add `\b` in front - `"""\bflimFlam\((.*?)\)"""`.